# Преобразовать контур в набор координат

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, ввод, координаты

Во многих фото- и видеоредакторах существует инструмент рисования контура: ставишь точку, ставишь другую и появляется отрезок, ставишь третью, слегка двигая мышкой, и прямая превращается в кривую и так далее пока не замкнёшь контур.

Существует ли программа, в которой я могу рисовать контур (например, обводить границы какого-то объекта на изображении), а сам этот контур преобразовать в набор координат.
Например, если я нарисую часть параболы, скажем, от 0 до 1, то как результат программа конвертирует это в такой набор: [[0, 0], [0.01 , 0.01^2], [0.02, 0.02^2], [0.03, 0.03^2], ..., [0.99, 0.99^2], [1, 1]].

(Шаг 0.01 выбрал для примера)

Спасибо

Comment: Существует. То что вы ищете, называется векторная графика. А формулы для прямых и кривых например можно найти в файлах в формате SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Решение

В C# существует пространство имён `System.Windows.Ink`. Для его использования в файле проекта (.NET Core) укажите

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <!--other props-->
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Теперь вы можете использовать этот пэймспэйс. Документация (ссылки #1,2)

## Ссылки

- [Ссылка #1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.ink?view=netcore-3.1) – `System.Windows.Ink`: документация (en-US)
- [Ссылка #2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.ink?view=netcore-3.1) – `System.Windows.Ink`: документация (ru-RU (машинный перевод))

Comment: Я предоставил готовый фрэймворк, если писать свою программу для этой цели, то можно просто свихнуться!

Answer (score 0):

Рыскал, рыскал и нашёл. Почти то, что я хотел, но для меня достаточно. 
https://www.mobilefish.com/services/record_mouse_coordinates/record_mouse_coordinates.php
Спасибо всем, кто помогал